# Conditions on $f$ to have $ \int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^1\int_{z=0}^1 \frac{f(x)}{(x-y)^2 (y-z)} dz dy dx $ finite?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Suppose that $f$ is a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ function.

$$ \int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^1\int_{z=0}^1 \frac{f(x)}{(x-y)^2 (y-z)} dz dy dx $$

Which are the conditions on $f$ that makes this integral finite ?

Thank you by advance.

Comment: What have you tried? You can at least compute the innermost integral yourself! The $dy$ integral is also not too hard to do! Once these are computed, it becomes easiert to answer the question.

Comment: The problem is not in the regularity of $f$, the problem is that $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dz}{y-z}$$ is not well-defined for any $y\in(0,1)$. Do you want to compute the principal value of the integral?